# How to print the output weights for the output layer in BERT?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, bert-language-model

I would like to print the output vector/tensor in BERT an wasn't sure how to do it.  I've been using the following example to walk myself through it:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pTuQhug6Dhl9XalKB0zUGf4FIdYFlpcX

Its a simple classification problem, but I want to be able to get the output vector before we classify the training examples.  Can someone point to where in the code I can do this and how?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the weights to the output layer or the logits? I think you want the logits, it is more work but better in the long run to subclass so you can play with it yourself. Here part of subclass I did where I wanted dropout and more control. I'll just include it here where you can access all the parts of the model

```
class MyBert(BertPreTrainedModel):
    def __init__(self, config, dropout_prob):
        super().__init__(config)
        self.num_labels = 2

        self.bert = BertModel(config)
        self.dropout = torch.nn.Dropout(dropout_prob)
        self.classifier = torch.nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, self.num_labels)

        self.init_weights()

    def forward(self,
        input_ids=None,
        attention_mask=None,
        token_type_ids=None,
        position_ids=None,
        head_mask=None,
        inputs_embeds=None,
        labels=None,):

        outputs = self.bert(
            input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            token_type_ids=token_type_ids,
            position_ids=position_ids,
            head_mask=head_mask,
            inputs_embeds=inputs_embeds,
        )

        pooled_output = outputs[1]

        pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)

        outputs = (logits,) + outputs[2:]  # add hidden states and attention if they are here
        if labels is not None:
            loss_fct = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
            loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
            outputs = (loss,) + outputs

        return outputs  # (loss), logits, (hidden_states), (attentions)
```